# Preserve NA areas in resampled raster

Tags: raster, r, resampling, aggregate

I got a raster image with 2m pixel size, there are some areas with value 1 (black) and roads with value NA (white):

[image]

It is made from a rasterized shape:

[image]

Now I resample my raster to 5 m pixels, the roads are now sometimes gone. How can I preserve these structures? Eg cut out the streets in this resolution.

[image]

Comment: And for clarity, you don't have the original vector data at this point? You have a raster you need to resample?

Comment: I would go for an aggregation with a function like `if (anyNA(x)) return NA else return x[1])`.

Comment: Right now I use aggregate in R, na.rm should do the same as your suggested if statement.
```aggregate(layer,fact=5, fun = modal, na.rm = TRUE) ```